# Do unsigned integers get promoted to signed? What is the type of expression (uint16_t)-1 * (uint16_t)-1

Tags: c++, unsigned, integer-promotion

For `uint32_t` and `uint64_t` results are expected, but promotions for `uint8_t` and `uint16_t` are strange. Tests on c++14/c++17, gcc and clang, 64-bit linux, `sizeof(int) == 4`.

```
#include <cstdint>    
using namespace std;

static_assert( uint8_t(-1)*uint8_t(-1) == 0xfe01);  // OK, but why not 1?
static_assert( uint8_t(-1)*uint8_t(-1) == 1);       // error: static assertion failed
static_assert( uint16_t(-1)*uint16_t(-1) == 1);     // error: static_assert expression is not an integral constant expression
static_assert( uint32_t(-1)*uint32_t(-1) == 1);     // OK
static_assert( uint64_t(-1)*uint64_t(-1) == 1);     // OK
```

Is in the following case `std::uint16_t` promoted to int?

```
static_assert( uint16_t(-1)*uint16_t(-1) == uint16_t(uint16_t(-1)*uint16_t(-1)));
```

The compiler messages are:

```
error: static_assert expression is not an integral constant expression
static_assert( uint16_t(-1)*uint16_t(-1) == uint16_t(uint16_t(-1)*uint16_t(-1)));

note: value 4294836225 is outside the range of representable values of type 'int'
static_assert( uint16_t(-1)*uint16_t(-1) == uint16_t(uint16_t(-1)*uint16_t(-1)));
```

More interestingly the same assert for `std::uint8_t` is correct, but *fails*:

```
static_assert( uint8_t(-1)*uint8_t(-1) == uint8_t(uint8_t(-1)*uint8_t(-1)));  //error: static_assert failed
static_assert( uint8_t(-1)*uint8_t(-1) == 0xfe01);  // does not fail
```

So it looks like `uint8_t` is promoted to `uint16_t`, but `uint16_t` is promoted to *signed* `int`. `uint32_t` is not promoted `uint64_t`.

Anyone can tell me why these promotions are done, is it specified in standard, or can differ on different implementations?

Comment: Converting `-1` to any unsigned integral type gives the maximum value that type can represent.   It is not possible to represent the value `-1` in an unsigned type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it looks like `uint8_t` is promoted to `uint16_t`, but `uint16_t` is promoted to signed int. `uint32_t` is not promoted `uint64_t`.

No, that's not correct. Only types narrower than int are promoted to int, so if int has more than 16 bits then both `uint8_t` and `uint16_t` will be promoted to int.

In the case of `uint8_t(-1)*uint8_t(-1)`, it's equivalent to `0xFF*0xFF` and the result will be 0xFE01

OTOH `uint16_t(-1)*uint16_t(-1)` is the same as `0xFFFF*0xFFFF` which results in 0xFFFE0001 = 4294836225 and is outside int's range. And signed overflow is undefined behavior

Comment: So why uint8_t(-1)*uint8_t(-1) == 0xfe01, and not 0xfffffe01 (32-bit)?

Comment: @user2622016 `uint8_t(-1)` is 0xFF, 0xFF*0xFF completely lies inside int's range. There's no overflow happening there. uint8_t(0xFF) is zero extended to int(0xFF) instead of sign extended because it's an unsigned type

Comment: Do you know how to suppress the promotion to signed int, and get it promoted to unsigned int? I want to have results of uint16_t multiplication to be unsigned type, so no UB, on every architecture, even if sizeof(int) == 2 or sizeof(int)==8.

Comment: OK, I get it. I need explicit cast to unsigned in between to suppress cast to signed int:  uint16_t(unsigned(uint16_t(-1))*unsigned(uint16_t(-1))) == 1

Comment: `Do you know how to suppress the promotion to signed int` Use `unsigned`. Not as unsigned types, but as `unsigned(uint16_t(-1))`. Ie. explicitly convert the value to a type that has rank greater or equal to that of an `int`. Something along `static_assert(uint16_t(unsigned(uint16_t(-1))*unsigned(uint16_t(-1))) == 1);`

Answer (score 2):

> Do unsigned integers get promoted to signed?

It depends on the size of the operand in relation to size of `int`. But yes, it is typical.

> ```
> static_assert( uint8_t(-1)*uint8_t(-1) == 0xfe01);  // OK, but why not 1?
> ```

It is not 1 because `uint8_t(-1)` is 255 and 255*255 is 65025. On systems with 32 bit int, that is within representable values.

> So it looks like uint8_t is promoted to uint16_t

No. Promotions always happen to `int` or integer of higher rank. `uint8_t` could be promoted to a 16 bit type on systems where `int` is 16 bits, but since all values of `uint8_t` are representable by signed `int`, that will be the result of the promotion.

> can differ on different implementations?

Range of representable values differ between language implementations, which affects what the promoted type will be.

> is it specified in standard

Yes.

> Do you know how to suppress the promotion to signed int, and get it promoted to unsigned int?

No, there is no way to change the promotions. But you can cast the value to the desired type explicitly so that there is no promotion.

Comment: Thanks! I went with: uint16_t(unsigned(uint16_t(0xFFFF))*unsigned(uint16_t(0x8001))). There is no UB, and result is uint16_t.

Answer (score 0):

Arithmetic operators do not accept types smaller than `int` as arguments.
For smaller arguments integral promotion to `int` is applied.

This is the reason for some inconsistency in results:

- when multiplying types smaller than `int` you get promotion,
- when multiplying larger types you don't (if they are the same).

The exact rules are too complicated to summarize without making an error, but are described in those CppReference articles:

- [Implicit conversions: Integral promotion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion)
- [Arithmetic operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic)